# android: how to do a smart email sending

Tags: android

My program has a email function. There are two activities, A and B. The email function is in activity B. When I click email button, it will pop up a dialog to let user to choose whose to send. then will call email. 
The problem is, every time when I click send, it will be return to the dialog(choose list). Is there anyway to let the program return to activity A automatilcally when user click send button. I can't do a onclick listerner becase email system is out of my control.
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can finish activity b manually by calling `finish()`

Comment: how can i do that. if i add finish() in onclick event, it will but without send mail. how can i know if email has been sent successfully?

Comment: Do you get any status response or exception if something has gone wrong while trying to send an email?

Answer (score 2):

in the on click function of the dialogue that you have implemented try calling dialog.dismiss() before switching to Activity B.